# how to extract & print cursor values outside function in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am new to pl/sql. My doubt might be basic, but i am unable to figure out the answer. Any help is highly appreciated.Here is the question.

I created a function which returns cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_empNumber (dept_name varchar2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
    l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN 
    OPEN l_rc FOR
        select DISTINCT emp_NUMBER FROM emp where department_NAME = dept_name;

    RETURN l_rc;
END ;
```

If I want to access the above returned cursor by calling the function, how should i do that? Tried below code but that's giving errors.Since i am trying this in Oracle Apex, it just says compilation errors,does not provide any further error details.

```
DECLARE
    cnumber number;
    CURSOR c1 IS get_bugNumber ('John');
BEGIN
    OPEN c1; 

    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO cnumber ;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Emp_No= ' || cnumber );
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Comment: get_empNumber isn't even called in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a ref cursor. Declare one and assign the result of the function to it:

Demo function:

```
create or replace function f
    return sys_refcursor
as
    c sys_refcursor;
begin
    open c for select 'Hello, world' as text from dual;
    return c;
end f;
```

Test:

```
declare
    mycursor sys_refcursor;

    type myrectype is record
        ( text varchar2(100) );
    r myrectype;
begin
    mycursor := f();

    loop
        fetch mycursor into r;
        exit when mycursor%notfound;

        dbms_output.put_line(r.text);
    end loop;

    close mycursor;
end;
```

Comment: How can i print the cursor values.Since cursor contains list of emp numbers, isthe below code corrcet?                                                        
       mycursor := f();                                    
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mycursor );

Comment: got it. used loop.                                                                                                  
        TYPE MyRec IS RECORD (col1 VARCHAR2(10), col2 
         VARCHAR2(20), ...);  --define the record
        rec MyRec;                                                                                     
        LOOP
       FETCH refCursor INTO rec;
       EXIT WHEN refCursor%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line(rec.col1||','||rec.col2||','||...);
       END LOOP;

Comment: Updated answer.